# Can I add attribute value to selector in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I have been reading about selectors all over and would now like to know if there is a way how I could send a value for function attribute over selector.

I have a method:

```
@objc func acceptBiometrics(newValue: Int){
}
```

And a selector:

```
#selector(acceptBiometrics(newValue:))
```

So is there a way I could send lets say 1 as new value, so that I could have two selector that call the same function, just with different value?

EDIT 1:
I am then sending this selector to some view controller to create my own alert view controller with a button. So the selector gets called in a totally different view controller. Is it the only way to do this then to also send that vc also the value I want to send with selector?
There isn't a way I could do something like #selector(self.acceptBiometrics(newValue:**1**))

Comment: where are you setting the selector, to a button?

Comment: once you perform selector there is an argument `withObject`. Have you tried using this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418764-perform

Comment: @NeverHopeless So do I have to also send the value to the part of the code that then calls this selector?

Comment: But in another view controller `self` will be something different

Comment: @EneaDume I edited the question to give additional info how thing works

Comment: A selector is the _name_ of a method, not a _call_ to a method.  You cannot use it to pass anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't**.

You can use the `button.tag` and set 1 (or any other `Int` value) to it.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.tag = 1
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(acceptBiometrics(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Then on your handler:

```
@objc func acceptBiometrics(_ sender : UIButton) {
    print(sender.tag)
}
```

**Notes:**

A `tag` attribute is an `Int` variable, so if you want any other `Type` you should create a custom `UIButton` with just a new variable.

The `tag` default value is 0, which means if 0 is a possible value in your logic, you should also do the custom component approach.

As @matt pointed out, "a selector is the *name* of a method, not a *call* to a method".

As @Sulthan pointed out, "Subclassing is the real solution".

A subclass would look like this:

```
class ButtonWithValue : UIButton {
    var value : Int? // note that this could be any Type.
}
```

Then your instantiate it, and update your sender parameter type to `ButtonWithValue`. Inside the handler you check for `sender.value`

Comment: Using tags is never a good idea. Subclassing is the real solution.

Comment: @Sulthan Would it be possible to subclass Selector class so that I could send attributes with it?

Comment: @schmru No. A selector is literally a string containing name of a method.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass the value with a selector, Use the following method to pass Int value using `UIbutton` tag.

```
button.tag = 5
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(acceptBiometrics(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

**Function**

```
@objc func acceptBiometrics(_ sender: UIbutton){
    print(sender.tag) //Output 5
}
```

Comment: So basically the Idea is that I set the tags on buttons and then I the function I check the tag of the button and based on that I will know what button was clicked?

Comment: Yes, that is the most common approach to pass parameters in a selector.

Comment: Ok no issue for that, assign a different tag to each button, and you can get easily which button you have tapped using tag.